# Не получается подключить OpenCV к Clion

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

помогите подключить OpenCV в Clion, папка `Build` находится в `D:\OpenCV\opencv`.
`CMakeLists.txt` в Clion выглядит так:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(Pacman)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set("OpenCV_DIR" "D:\\OpenCV\\opencv\\build")
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

include_directories(D:\\OpenCV\\opencv\\build\\include\\)

add_executable(YourExecutable main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(YourExecutable ${OpenCV_LIBS})
add_executable(Pacman main.cpp)
```

Код вообще не компилируется.

Тогда я попробовал записать вот так:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(Pacman)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set("OpenCV_DIR" "D:/OpenCV/opencv/build/x64/vc16/lib")
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

include_directories(D:/OpenCV/opencv/build/include/opencv2)

add_executable(YourExecutable main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(YourExecutable ${OpenCV_LIBS})
add_executable(Pacman main.cpp)
```

Так код компилируется, но не видит заголовочные файлы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]